# create javascript action from the outcome of a php if/else statement

Tags: javascript, php

I have this code that's working just fine in PHP:

```
<?php    
    $doUPDATE = mysqli_query($con, $sqlUPDATE);
    if (!$doUPDATE) {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    if ($OutcomeValue <> 'null') {                  

      $sqlMOVE  = "INSERT INTO results SELECT * FROM report WHERE LineID = $LineID ;" ;
      $sqlDELETE = "DELETE FROM report where LineID = $LineID ;" ;
      $doMOVE = mysqli_query($con, $sqlMOVE);
      if (!$doMOVE) 
        {
          die('Could not MOVE data: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
      $doDELETE = mysqli_query($con, $sqlDELETE);
      if (!$doDELETE) 
        {
          die('Could not DELETE data: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        } 
    }
```

I understand that PHP is server side, and javaScript is client side, but I'm wondering if there is a way to set some type of variable so that AFTER this query is done running, if the `if ($OutcomeValue <> 'null')` evaluated to false and executed the code, I could create a javascript alert to notify the user that they had deleted a record.

I'm not sure how I would go about this though....

I know how to make the alert... just not how to get it to trigger only when THAT particular section of PHP code has been executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
if (!$doMove) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(<?php echo json_encode(mysqli_error($con)); ?>);
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not be using procedural PHP, it's 2014, but that's besides the point. You could do a script tag on a php page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var blah = <?php echo $variable;?>
</script>
```

Just echo the outcome value and now you can access it in js